# django says No module named 'profiles.forms' but a already created it

Tags: django

I created an app using `./manage.py startapp profiles` then in the app i create a file called `forms.py` and it looks like this

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Profile

User = get_user_model()


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    email = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['location', 'bio']
```

in `views.py`
when I try `from .forms import ProfileForm`  it shows error says

```
    from .forms import ProfileForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'profiles.forms'
```

Comment: Have you added: INSTALLED_APPS = ['profiles ']  in settings.py file?

Comment: Have you made sure that the files are in the correct folder and that it contains a `__init__.py`?

Comment: @IqbalHussain yes of course

Comment: @Martí yes of course

Comment: I'd try to access the file via console. Maybe there's some typo or permission problem. If that works fine, I'd stop any server you may have (locally) and I'd try cleaning all `.pyc` files.